# Call a javascript function after 5 sec of last key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with an `<input type=text />` and I want to call a javascript function after 5 seconds of the last key press, and every time a new key is pressed, this timer should reset and only call the function after 5 seconds.

How can I do this?

I'm using jQuery.

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the last key pressed when the user has the input field currently active?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
var timeout;
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function() {
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(myFunction, 5000)
})
```

Comment: Just remember that the timeout function works in milliseconds. That is why he used 5000.

Comment: Technically the setting to null is superfluous.

Comment: It is working without making timeout null.. i didn't  understand whats the requirement to make it null @Crescent Fresh

Comment: I really wanted to thank you! Simple but very effective.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693863/3303195) is great, but remember that you need to enable this code after the documents loads and after the function loads to clear the timeout.

Here is the complete code:

```js
var timeout;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input[type=text]').keypress(function() {
          if(timeout) {
              clearTimeout(timeout);
              timeout = null;
          }
          timeout = setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
      });
    });
  
 var myFunction = new function() { 
   alert('myFunction is running');
   clearTimeout(timeout); // this way will not run infinitely
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't use jQuery, you could also have a look at the debouncing function described [here](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/).

Steve