# Autosubmit single form input box when filled

Tags: javascript

I have been asked for a very short simple project to allow the magnetic stripe of an ID card to be read, and display the result from a database if dues are paid or not paid.

I have all this working and am trying to remove some annoying behaviors.  The magnetic strip information is being captured in a form with a single input text field.  The user must click on submit to proceed to a second hidden page where I parse out the information and assign to variables, preparing for the database search.

I would like to remove the requirement that the user has to press the submit button. It seems that I should be able to trigger off the length of the input variable being greater than 0.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

.
.

```
<body onload = document.get_id.fID_Num.focus();>
```

.
.

```
<form id="get_id" name="get_id" method="post" action="card_swipe_process.asp">
  <table width="100%" border="5" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
          <td width="45%" class="PIN_LABEL">Swipe ID Card</td>
          <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="45%"><label for="fID_Num"></label>
          <input name="fID_Num" type="text" id="fID_Num" maxlength="15" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="PIN_LABEL">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="PIN_LABEL">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="ID_NUM_ENTER" id="ID_NUM_ENTER"              value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be nice to, at the very least, wrap the `onload` attribute in quotes.

Comment: Please show use **how** "*the magnetic strip information is being captured in the input text field*". We might find a working event for you then. Also, what browser/environment does the client use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have code somewhere that reads in the card number and puts it in the box. Just add `document.getElementById('get_id').submit()` to that code. This way, the user can still type in a number if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem with a barcode reader that acted as a "keyboard wedge".

Start a timer for 300ms. After each "keystroke" clear and restart the timer. Once the timer times out, submit the form.

See: [How can I call a function after a person stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172816/how-can-i-call-a-function-after-a-person-stops-typing)

```
var timer;

function onKeyUpHandler(e){
    timer = setTimeout(function() {document.get_id.submit()}, 300)    
}

function onKeyDownHandler(e) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function sub(){
var id = document.getElementById('ID_NUM_ENTER').value;
if(id.length >= 0)
document.getElementByTagName('form').submit();
</script>
```

This has to work and i suggest here using ajax when you are dealing with database and it works faster.