# how to call javascript function using time period ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
var refresh;
function refresh(timeoutPeriod){
    refresh = setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod);
}  
makeClientRequest('live','liveFeed','');
window.onload=refresh(5000);   
<script>
```

I want to call this function every 5 sec. I try that way.but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a javascript function after 5 sec of last key press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693849/call-a-javascript-function-after-5-sec-of-last-key-press)

Comment: You are getting the downvotes because it does not appear you have tried to search for your answer. The duplicate question marked above is an exact duplicate -- even the time frame is the same. Please show an effort to research your problem; it is good for you, and good for our community here. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to a lack of research, "it didn't work" doesn't help describe the specific problem to us, which makes it more difficult to efficiently help (especially if the code is complex).

Answer (score 3):

Try `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```
refresh = setInterval(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod);
```

`setTimeout` will call the function only once after the specified time period. But `setInterval` will call the function on specified interval of time